# Encapsulation of structure in class

Tags: c++

Is it good practice to encapsulate a structure used by a class inside the class if only the class uses it and not the user who will end up using the class, or does it not matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally poor practice to expose any internal details in the headers.

See [GotW #100: Compilation Firewalls](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/) for more details.